# ZonedDateTime America/Phoenix zone to GMT having issue

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I want to Convert America/Phoenix to GMT

```
ZonedDateTime zdtPhoenix1 = ZonedDateTime.of(2022, 6, 27, 10, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/Phoenix"));
    System.out.println(zdtPhoenix1);
    System.out.println(zdtPhoenix1.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("GMT")));
```

Out Put

```
2022-06-27T10:00-07:00[America/Phoenix]
2022-06-27T17:00Z[GMT]
```

I am expecting GMT

```
2022-06-27T03:00Z[GMT]
```

As ZoneOffset of America/Phoenix is -7 hours but the actual output is +7 hours

Comment: 10:00 in Phoenix is 17:00 GMT - the sun (apparently) travels from East to West (it already passed GMT (England) before reaching America) || actually yourself wrote it correctly: "the offset of Phoenix is -7 hours - so 17:00 GMT (the reference time zone) is `17:00 - 7:00` in the time zone that is `-7:00`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`10:00-07:00` is not an arithmetic expression.

`-07:00` means that your clock is 7 hours *behind* GMT. So that means that when it is 10 o'clock in GMT, 10 o'clock in America/Phoenix will be 7 hours later.

So yes, if it's 10:00 in America/Phoenix, then it's already 17:00 in GMT.

Answer (score 0):

The offset of America/Phoenix is -7 hours from Greenwich/UTC, meaning time in GMT/UTC is America/Phoenix +7 hours.

The result you are getting is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Java doc of `withZoneSameInstant` method of ZonedDateTime mentions that

> Returns a copy of this date-time with a different time-zone,retaining the instant.

So if its 05(17) PM in GMT , then at *same time* (you can say instant), Phoenix clock shows 10 AM : ( 17-7 = 10).

So result is correct.